# Footer Background Image Position Problem with IE7 only!

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I can not figure out how to fix this problem in IE7. It works fine everywhere else!

the background images in the footer float to the top of the page...only in IE7!

hope someone knows how to fix this before my client implodes!!

if whoever fixes this lives in austin, i will buy you a beer! :)

test site:
http://evergreen.sweetassmedia.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't live in Austin (or even America), but I found the solution to your problem :)

On `.background_texture`, remove `height: 325px`.

That fixes IE7, and I didn't notice any changes in other browsers.

Comment: thank you thirtydot!!! that did the trick!!! if you ever come to austin, I will buy you that beer, and Kyle for trying! thank you Kyle for giving it a go! I appreciate it!!!